# HVAC Condensate Line P Trap

Tags: plumbing, hvac, air-conditioning, p-trap, condensate

I've consistently experienced issues with my AC. I won't get into all of the background, but I would like to know if the pictured condensate line is appropriately trapped. The vertical PVC pipe is not capped, and I assume that doesn't allow for the appropriate suction. Curious to hear additional input! Thanks in advance.

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic3]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Suction" is not desirable.

The main problem there is likely inadequate slope on the line coming straight out from the air handler, and/or inadequate slope on the leg to the air gap. The line across the top front appears to have adequate slope.

The actual **trap** is beyond the air gap, in larger diameter pipe.

In my biased opinion, the second major likely cause of problem is the use of small diameter pipes and sharp elbows rather than larger pipe and DWV sweeps for drainage plumbing. HVAC types are all about "it's just clear condensate, I can run a tiny pipe" and then they are shocked, just shocked when it clogs up (because that condensate comes from air, that has dust, that includes spores, and things grow...)

The open pipe stub (on top of the furnace) is probably intended to allow you to clean the vertical pipe, but given there's no access to clean the horizontal pipes, that is of limited benefit.

If you are actually asking about the open pipe on the P trap entrance, that's quite specifically to prevent suction from draining the trap and allowing sewer gas into the house. It's a "standpipe" forming an "Air Gap" and is utterly required. The P trap itself appears to be correctly installed to a drain line with a vent line extending upwards, though we can't tell if that drain line or vent line are clear and functioning. If you pour water into the standpipe it should drain away quickly, but water should remain in the lower part of the  trap when you stop pouring water in, not be sucked out into the drain.

**Post-update Ugh.** Well ***that*** was a sloppy hack job, as revealed by your latest/last picture - the vent line is not complete, and is venting sewer gas into your house. If there was an inspection of this work, the inspector should be fired and anything they passed should be re-inspected, and whoever did the work should be publicly shamed as well as being made to fix it to code. Or perhaps taken to court to force them to pay for someone **actually competent** to fix it to code. That open vent pipe inside the house on the smelly side of the trap is certainly the source of your sewer gas smell, and a code violation the size of a gigantic tortoise held up by 4 elephants...

It should either extend all the way through the roof, or connect to another vent line that goes all the way through the roof. *Some might suggest a "Studor" vent also known as an AAV (air admittance valve.) I would not be among the "some" - those things fail, and your house stinks again, and you replace them, and they fail again - a vent through the roof works, **reliably.** Perhaps as a very temporary, quick stop-gap while you get the vent to the roof sorted.*

Comment: Thanks for all of your knowledge and insight!   

The issue I am trying to resolve is that when running the system, there is a faint sewer gas smell throughout my condo. It is hard for me to pinpoint the origin, but it is strongest near the furnace closet (which is also near the bathroom). The vertical PVC pipe to the left is connect to (perhaps through) the floor at the bottom and then is left open and exposed within the closet. I'm unsure if this pipe is some sort of waste vent or what it connects to. I've added pictures to the thread. Curious to hear your thoughts! Thanks again.

Comment: OMFG, pardon my anglo-saxon. Your original pictures implied (since that was not visible and there were two other "open at the top PVC pipes" to see) that this line went through the ceiling of the closet to the roof (or connected to some other vent line to the roof) - the last picture you just added is the zinger -  that is definitely wrong, a problem, needs fixed, and the source of your sewer gas smell. It should either extend all the way through the roof, or connect to another vent line that goes all the way through the roof.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for all of your insight on this.  Do you think there is a reasonable case to be made to take the contractor, or perhaps the developer (whom I purchased the condo from), to court and have them pay for the necessary repairs?

Comment: Reasonable - yes. That is a blantant violtion that should never have been left like that. Given the depressing way things work out too often in court, can't say if it will be cost effective, but perhaps if it fits in "small claims court" and you don't have to spend twice as much on a lawyer as you would fixing it....? Might be a question for the legal stack, might not, I haven't spent any time there.